# Import .frm and .opt files to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL 5.5.1.1 downloaded and installed from : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

I want to import .frm and .opt database files from my local machine to my mysql database.

I created a new Databbase connection to help me import the files from my machine. But I am unable to import .frm files as I keep getting error message: Format not supported.

Can someone please help me on how I could import files to MySQL client??

Thank you,
J

Comment: Can you please elaborate? .frm file is just a database structure descriptor. opt is just overall database options file. They contain no data. And of course they cannot be imported to MySQL client. They are for MySQL server.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As far importing any MySQL data, three(3) things need to considered.

## MyISAM

Importing a MyISAM table is a simple as moving three files with the extensions `.frm`, `.MYD`, and `.MYI` files for the given table into a MySQL folder. For example, if the table name is mydata, then the three(3) files

- `mydata.frm`
- `mydata.MYD`
- `mydata.MYI`

The following could be the nightmare of nightmares. Importing InnoDB depends entirely on many factors that fall into one of two categories:

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled [default])

All InnoDB data and index pages are located in `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`. This file must be moved from your source machine (Server-S) to the target machine (Server-T) and placed in the same absolute path. In fact, here is the shocker: Server-S and Server-T must be the same. In other words, you cannot import and export InnoDB `.ibd` files to other machines. They can only be imported and exported on the same machine the `.ibd` was created on.

You would also have to move /var/ib/mysql/ib_logfile0 and /var/ib/mysql/ib_logfile1 from Server-S and place them in the same absolute path on Server-T.

You also must make sure that every InnoDB variable set in /etc/my.cnf from Server-S must be set in /etc/my.cnf on Server-T.

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled)

For every InnoDB table, there will be two files. For example, if the InnoDB table in the mydata database is called mytable, you will have `/var/lib/mysql/mydata/mytable.frm` and /var/lib/mysql/mydata/mytable.ibd. The `.ibd` file contains data and index pages for the table. To import the individual table you must

1. Place the `mytable.frm` in `/var/lib/mysql/mydata folder` on Server-T
2. Place the `mytable.ibd` in `/var/lib/mysql/mydata folder` on Server-T
3. Run `ALTER TABLE mydata.mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

Make sure you have the `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` in the same place it was imported from.

## Moral of the story

Please do not use IMPORT TABLESPACE techniques across different servers. Just do a mysqldump of everything and import the mysqldump. Logical dumps are always the safest way to go !!!

Comment: thank you so much!!! that was really helpful. I went crazy trying to figure it out.

Comment: Does the part "Server-S and Server-T must be the same." mean that when replacing the system disk it's impossible to import InnoDB frm files?

Comment: i have the same question as @Kawu .

Comment: @Kawu this was true to some extent considering the answer is over two years old. Later versions of MySQL have the ability to transport databases in a cleaner fashion these days. Please read the MySQL Documentation on Transportable Tablespaces : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html

Comment: +1 - This was my last straw for what I've encountered yesterday and finally it works! This is the simplest solution I've come across the internet for this kind of issue. Why I didn't found this first?

Comment: using the innodb_file_per_table enabled method, I get the error `table 'mydata.mytable' doesn't exist`.  Of course I'm not using mydata.mytable literally, I am using the db.tablename of the pertinent database/tables. MySql 5.7.16 Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct with modern versions

Answer (score 8):

I did a mysql import using the files on xampp. I have very many databases so I did not want to go through the mysqldump route. The process was:

1. Install the new xampp, but do not enable the services
2. Update **my.ini** to include any custom settings I had on the previous install.
3. Confirm that mysql is starting successfully
4. Copy over all the database folders (inside the data folder) from the old install with the exception of **mysql**, **phpmyadmin** and **webauth**.
5. Confirm that mysql is starting successfully
6. Copy over **ib_logfile0**, **ib_logfile1** and **ibdata1**. Rename the files first, do not overwrite just in case something goes wrong.
7. Confirm that mysql is starting successfully
8. Copy over the following files from the **data/mysql** folder: **db.frm**, **db.MYD**, **db.MYI**, **user.frm**, **user.MYD**, **user.MYI**. Do not overwrite the new ones just in case it doesn't work.
9. Confirm that mysql is starting successfully

At the end of the process I had mysql working perfectly with all my databases and users intact.

Comment: if doing on linux, don't forget to set the owner and group of the files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1. Similarly, set the owner of the database files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy desired 'data' folder to target mysql data folder, after renaming current 'data' folder, after stop mysql service. And export to sql file with phpmyadmin, and restore current data folder, and import desired data sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think the great problem you may be experiencing comes from the fact that you cannot even view these .frm files in the phpmyadmin interface (because they really are incomplete sets). I'd suggest you delete these files from the current location and use phpmyadmin to re-create the these tables as SQL under "query" tab [delete IFF you do have database script of everything. if not, you may still get this from the old dump. if not gaian, do NOT delete). Thanks : chagbert.