# How can I recover sql tables from a broken Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I made a mistake in my latest upgrade to Xampp, I copied my old Xampp directory to C:/Xampp - Copy but I forgot to export out the mysql tables. I then uninstalled xampp and installed the new version.

I tried to access the phpmyadmin from the Xampp - Copy folder but I cannot get access to it to dump its tables, is there anyway I can gain access to my old tables?

Comment: Have you check the `c:/xampp-copy/mysql` directory? or try to find mysql folder in `xampp-copy`, at there you find your `.sql` files.

Comment: Xampp doesn't store it in .mysql format so I cannot read it.

Comment: what is the .extension of the files which are stored in `c:/xampp-copy/mysql/data` ?

Comment: .frm .myd and .myi

Answer (score 0):

```
c:/xampp-copy/mysql/data
```

See This directory for your database tables.

if these are in unreadable format then i think problem is with your Database engine. Checkout the following guidelines.

[InnoDB Backup and Recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html)

[Moving or Copying InnoDB Tables to Another Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-migration.html)

See This Answer also. [Import .frm and .opt files to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745221/import-frm-and-opt-files-to-mysql)

Comment: But that is the way Xampp stores them by default, you need the phpmyadmin to read them but I cannot access the phpmyadmin of the old install. I was hoping to some how connect to the old phpadmin or convert the data folders to .sql format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working through the new PHP My Admin, all resolved now.