# Restore the mysql database from .frm files

Tags: mysql

I have dumped all my tables everyweek to got the backup. But later I understand that it is only storing the .frm file of the table. It is not showing .MYD and .MYI files of a table. So I have only my .frm file of the database with me and also mydatabase is innodb. So can I get my database with data in the database?

Comment: how did you dump? if you used mysqldump, then you should get sql statements that can be used to restore data or table structure or both, unless you only dumped the table structure in which case you can only restore the table structure.

Answer (score 79):

Yes this is possible. It is not enough you just copy the `.frm` files to the to the databse folder but you also need to copy the `ib_logfiles` and `ibdata` file into your data folder. I have just copy the `.frm` files and copy those files and just restart the server and my database is restored.

After copying the above files execute the following command -

> sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

The above command will change the file owner under mysql and it's folder to MySql user. Which is important for mysql to read the `.frm` and `ibdata` files.

Comment: What if when I have three old databases moved to one which have few databases already?

Comment: Could someone passing through this thread provide an answer to the follow up comment above posted at Jul 26 '14 at 8:22? TIA.

Comment: @user359187 What happen if phpmyadmin version is changed?

Comment: @user359187 - you are the man, it helped and saved a lot of time

Comment: What if you have a new databases. If we overwite the ibdata, we overwrite the new databases. How can we sold this?

Comment: For people getting worried about overwriting existing ibdata1, just make a backup for current mysql folder, then do @user359187 solution, export dump and recover the backed mysql folder.

Comment: I get "Can't connect to local MySQL server..."  error after using these steps, would really love to know how to fix.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works on Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 18):

Just might be useful for someone:

I could only recover frm files after a disaster, at least I could get the table structure from FRM files by doing the following:

1- create some dummy tables with at least one column and SAME NAME with frm files in a new mysql database.

2-stop mysql service

3- copy and paste the old frm files to newly created table's frm files, it should ask you if you want to overwrite or not for each. replace all.

4-start mysql service, and you have your table structure...

regards.
anybudy

Comment: Dear anonymous user, you saved my life today! It worked great for me! Just copying the .frm files wasn't enough indeed.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Table doesnt exist error. although i can see columns.

Comment: any way of recovering the data of the tables from the .frm files?

Comment: I have same issue. I also want to recover from only .frm files. Does there any way?

Comment: The steps I explained, helps you recover the "table structure" from .frm files, as user359187 answered you will need some additional files to recover data too.

Comment: Today an old server with mysql 5.6 has is hdd crashed.
The IT service was able to extract mysql folder, so they make a zip and sended to me.
After investigating, the way I recovered the information was as follows:
Install mysql 5.6.
Stop the service.
Locate the data folder (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data).
Copy all the folders (databases) and ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1 from zip to this folder
Restart mysql server.

Using this steps, all my lost data was recovered from a crashed hdd
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 11):

I answered this question here, as well: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42932/24122

I recently experienced this same issue. I'm on a Mac and so I used MAMP in order to restore the Database to a point where I could export it in a MySQL dump.

You can read the full blog post about it here: http://www.quora.com/Jordan-Ryan/Web-Dev/How-to-Recover-innoDB-MySQL-files-using-MAMP-on-a-Mac

You must have:

-ibdata1

-ib_logfile0

-ib_logfile1

-.FRM files from your mysql_database folder

-Fresh installation of MAMP / MAMP Pro that you are willing to destroy (if need be)

1. SSH into your web server (dev, production, no difference) and browse to your mysql folder (mine was at /var/lib/mysql for a Plesk installation on Linux)
2. Compress the mysql folder
3. Download an archive of mysql folder which should contain all mySQL databases, whether MyISAM or innoDB (you can scp this file, or move this to a downloadable directory, if need be)
4. Install MAMP (Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP)
5. Browse to /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
6. Backup /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql to a zip archive (just in case)
7. Copy in all folders and files included in the archive of the mysql folder from the production server (mt Plesk environment in my case) EXCEPT DO NOT OVERWRITE:

   -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql/

   -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info

   -/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/performance_schema
8. And voila, you now should be able to access the databases from phpMyAdmin, what a relief!

But we're not done, you now need to perform a mysqldump in order to restore these files to your production environment, and the phpmyadmin interface times out for large databases.
Follow the steps here:

http://nickhardeman.com/308/export-import-large-database-using-mamp-with-terminal/

Copied below for reference. Note that on a default MAMP installation, the password is "root".

### **How to run mysqldump for MAMP using Terminal**

EXPORT DATABASE FROM MAMP[1]

**Step One:**
Open a new terminal window

**Step Two:**
Navigate to the MAMP install by entering the following line in terminal
    cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin
Hit the enter key

**Step Three:**
Write the dump command
    ./mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DATA_BASENAME] > [PATH_TO_FILE]
Hit the enter key

Example:

```
./mysqldump -u root -p wp_database > /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symposium10_wp/wp_db_onezero.sql
```

Quick tip: to navigate to a folder quickly you can drag the folder into the terminal window and it will write the location of the folder. It was a great day when someone showed me this.

**Step Four:**
This line of text should appear after you hit enter
Enter password:
So guess what, type your password, keep in mind that the letters will not appear, but they are there
Hit the enter key

**Step Five:**
Check the location of where you stored your file, if it is there, SUCCESS
Now you can import the database, which will be outlined next.

Now that you have an export of your mysql database you can import it on the production environment.

Answer (score 10):

I made use of `mysqlfrm` which is a great tool which generates table creation sql code from .frm files. I was getting this nasty table not found error although tables were being listed. Thus I used this tool to regenerate the tables. In ubuntu you need to install this as:

```
sudo apt install mysql-utilities
```

then,

```
mysqlfrm --diagnostic mysql/db_name/ > db_name.sql
```

Create a new database and then you can use,

```
mysql -u username -p < db_name.sql
```

However, this will give you the tables but not the data. In my case this was enough.

Comment: this will only give you the tables but not the data?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes! It is possible

Long approach but you can get all the data's using just `.frm` files. Of course, you need other files in the `mysql/data` directory.

### My Problem

One day my hard disk crashed and got the booting blue screen error. I try connecting with multiple machines and it didn't work. Since it is a booting error I was concerned about the files. and I tried with the secondary hard disk and try to recover the folders and files. I also backed up the full xampp folder `c:/xampp` just in case,  Because I had no back of the recent databases I got really worried about how to retrieve the database. we have a lot of clients' project management and personal doc in the database.

None of the methods listed on the StackOverflow comment works, at least for me.  It took me 2 full days googling for the answer to getting the data from the `.frm` files. Came across multiple approaches from many people but everything was frustrating and getting some error or another when implementing. If most of them get it working (based on their comment) then what am I missing.

**Because I was so desperate I even reinstall windows which result in losing all my software and tried again. But still the same error**

### THANKS to Dustin Davis

I found the solution in his blog and I managed to get it working exactly the same way he did. Let me give the credit to this guy, Dustin Davis (https://dustindavis.me/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows/). You could jump from here to his blog and try his method, pretty clear and easy to follow.

But there is something I discovered when trying his approach that he hasn't explained in his blog and I will try my best to explain how I did and what you need to look for.

### Follow this exactly

**IMPORTANT: Make sure you install the same version of XAMPP. You cannot copy-paste from older XAMPP to a new version. This will result in `__config` or `__tracking` errors.**

#### How to check your XAMPP version

1. Go to your xampp folder (you're backed up xampp).
2. Open the `readme_en.txt` file. which is in the root directory of the xampp.
3. You should see the version on top. `###### ApacheFriends XAMPP Version X.X.XX ######`

#### Files require to restore

`xampp(old folder)/mysql/data/`

```
ibdata1
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
<databasename>/*.frm
<databasename>/*.ibd
```

#### Step 1

1. After installing the same version of xampp.
2. **Do not start the apache or myql**

#### Step 2

- Go to the `mysql/data` folder and **replace** the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0`, and `ib_logfile1`
- Now copy paste your `database` folder from your old xampp backup to the newly installed xampp folder `c:/xampp/mysql/data/` that contain `.frm` and `.ibd` files, If you are not sure try with one database.

#### Step 3

- Go to `c:/xampp/mysql/bin` and look for `my.cn`.
- Open the `my.cn` file and look for `#skip-innodb` and under that look for the line that says `innodb_log_file_size=5M` change it to `170M`. `innodb_log_file_size=170M`. This is your log file size and if you are not sure just set it to `170`

#### Step 4

- Now open the file `mysql_start.bat` (Windows Batch file) that is in the `c:/xampp/` directory.
- Add `–innodb_force_recovery=6` after the `... --console`

  ```
   ....

   mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console -–innodb_force_recovery=6
   if errorlevel 1 goto error
   goto finish
  ```

#### Step 5

- Now Start your Apache and Mysql.
- Go to your `PHPMyAdmin` and check for your database and its tables. if you do not get any errors you are on the right track.
- **Stop the Apache and Mysql** and copy-paste the rest of the databases.

Answer (score 3):

I just copy pasted the database folders to data folder in MySQL, i.e. If you have a database called alto then find the folder alto in your MySQL -> Data folder in your backup and copy the entire alto folder and past it to newly installed MySQL -> data folder, restart the MySQL and this works perfect.

Comment: The restart was the key bit here - nice one!

Comment: Make sure to stop MYSQL first.

Answer (score 3):

Copy all file and replace to /var/lib/mysql , 
after that you must change owner of files to `mysql` 
**this is so important if mariadb.service restart has been faild**

> chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/*

and

> chmod -R 700 /var/lib/mysql/*

Answer (score 3):

After much trial and error I was able to get this working based on user359187 answer and [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-tablespace-is-missing-for-table/) blog post.

To get my old `.frm` and `.ibd` transferred to a new MySQL database after copying the files over and assigning MySQL ownership, the key for me was to then log into MySQL and connect to the new database then let MySQL do the work by importing the tablespace.

```
mysql> connect test;
mysql> ALTER TABLE t1 IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

This will import the data using the copied `.frm` and `.ibd` files.

I had to run the Alter command for each table separately but this worked and I was able to recover the tables and data.

Comment: This worked for me. The only reason why it was able to work was because I independently knew the database table schema structure. I was able to manually write CREATE statements and then follow the steps here to import. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before starting you should stop the WAMP services, or at least restart the services when prompted to start them.

On the old server instance navigate to the MySQL data folder by default this should look something similar to `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data\` where `mysql5.1.53` will be the version number of the previously installed MySQL database.

Inside this folder you should see a few files and folders. The folders are the actual MySQL databases, and contain a bunch of .frm files which we will require. You should recognise the folder names as the database names. These folder and all their contents can be copied directly to your MySQL data folder, you can neglect the default databases mysql, performance_schema, test.

If you started the server now you will see the databases are picked up, however the databases will contain none of the tables which were copied across. In order for the contents of the database to be picked up, back in the data folder you should see a file `ibdata1`, this is the data file for tables, copy this directly into the data folder, you should already have a file in your new data folder called “ibdata1″ so you may wish to rename this to `ibdata1.bak` before copying across the `ibdata1` from the old MySQL data folder.

Once this has been done Restart all the WAMP services. You can use PhpMyAdmin to check if your databases have been successfully restored.

Answer (score -1):

create a new database with same name 
copy the .frm .ibd files into **xampp/mysql/data/[databasename]/**

you will need ibdata file as well
which is found inside

**xampp/mysql/data/**
copy the previous ibdata1 file 
paste in the paste the file and replace it with the existing ibdata file

[***caution: you may loose the contents of the database which are newly created in the new ibdata file***]