# Restore tables and DBs from frm file and

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench, frm

Im trying to restore my Databases by frm files and ibdata1 that I did backup; I simply copy all of the files in mysql/data (which include different databases as folders which have .frm files for each single table and some other files in the " mysql/data" folder like ibdata1,... )to my new mysql (C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\data) but it did not restore databases! Did I miss anything?

PS:If someone can explain it step by step in a simple way I realy appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And not is more easy to make a mysql dump, export all the data you want as sql file, and later import from the new server, instead of copying all the files one by one? If you want more information can see the [oficial page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-server-administration-manage-data-import-export.html)

Comment: Hi these files are the only files that I have! the real databases have been deleted; can I restore my database from these .frm files? How?

Comment: I found something in the stackoverflow site that can help you, another person with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934745/restore-the-mysql-database-from-frm-files and in the same link, a link to another in dba http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/mysql-how-to-restore-table-stored-in-a-frm-and-a-ibd-file/42932#42932