# Exporting a table without using phpMyAdmin in MAMP

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a web application using ExtJS with a SQL Database hosted on phpMyAdmin using MAMP. About 2 weeks ago, I had to dump my old HD because of bad sectors and I got an SSD as a replacement. After installing my applications again (IDE's, Document Editing Softwares, MAMP, etc), I had to reinitialize my databases in phpMyAdmin.

Luckily, I had one of them online in production so I just exported the SQL from the server and I had a local copy again. However, there's this one other website that I do not have a backup to the SQL file of -- and I need to get that SQL file because I can't create it from memory (I think it had 30+ tables already).

I know I can plug in my old hard drive, boot from there, open MAMP, open phpMyAdmin, then export my database. However, that's too much work and I am not sure if that's a good idea.

Is there a way to extract the SQL file of a phpMyAdmin table by using the file directory/structure alone? I think MAMP is supposed to store the data somewhere so that phpMyAdmin knows where to get its SQL tables.

### Update

I found my "database" under `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ProjectName/` but they're `.frm` and I'm clueless on how to open this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: [Restore the mysql database from .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934745/restore-the-mysql-database-from-frm-files)

You'll need a couple more files other than the .frm, but you can solve it with the files alone, no need to plug in your old drive again.