# How to restore database in MySQL/phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp, database-restore

I was using the MAMP program to host my database locally on my laptop. I had a problem so I had to reinstall the MAMP software. Before I did that though, I copied my entire MAMP folder from my C drive to my desktop. Now that I have MAMP installed, I opened the startpage and then went to phpMyAdmin.

I want to know how I can restore my database? When I opened phpMyAdmin after reinstallation, I could see the database and the name of the tables. But when I click on the tables, it says the table doesn't exist. When I tried importing the table, there was an error and it didn't work. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: MySQL Error]

The copied database is in this location: `C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\MAMP\db\mysql\DatabaseName`. In the `DatabaseName` folder, there are the 3 tables which I had which have the `.frm` file extension. and then 1 file called `db.opt`. How can I restore the tables to my database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where should I post this question if not on Stack Overflow? Which community should I post this question on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It works very well.

You just need to copy the `ib_LogFiles` and the `ibData` file and it should all be fixed!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943833/6183565