# Mysql is not working into xamp

Tags: php, mysql

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>          This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>           improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>               Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>           the Windows Event Vi 09:09:06 PM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>               entire log window on the forums

In the error log

> mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
>
> Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
>       Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>        Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>       Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>       Aborting

what is the solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly on Xampp due to Plugin 'Aria'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170937/how-to-fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-due-to-plugin-aria)

Comment: Include more of the logs next time. The messages prior to this would enable enough information for a non-destructive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your Error log states that delete `aria_log.########` files

For removing that files you have to **Go to /xampp/mysql/data/**

And **Remove the Files which names start with aria_log.######.**

in folder there will be file which name will be `aria_log.00000001` most of the time it will be only one file but if there are more than 1 file then remove all of them,

Don't worry xampp will create another files of that type.

and after removing that files restart xammp, this time mysql will run perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This guy have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162264/7938027

1 - exit Xampp server

2 - go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory

3 - delete the ibdata1 file

4 - restart xampp server