# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. While Trying to start Mysql on Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

My xampp can't running mysql. Thousand solution on the internet I already do, but still don't give me the solution. This is the error log :

```
2018-05-30 02:14:31 1408 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

****************************
2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2018-05-30  2:14:31 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-83.0 started; log sequence number 546092343

2018-05-30  2:14:33 6096 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x208b)

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables

2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] Aborting
*******************************
```

Can anyone please help me..

Comment: Hav you tried `Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files`?

Comment: hi Sticky bit... I also readed this message, but I don't know how to run aria_chk -r mean... can u explain me please how to do it... thank u before...

Comment: Anyone knows could you please help me... The only thing I have is data on folder xampp\mysql\data ... and when I try copy it to another computer, the table shown but cannot be open : MySql error.. table doesn't exist

Comment: This issue has already been answered here [this will help you sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170937/how-to-fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-due-to-plugin-aria)

Answer (score 11):

In your error log there is log which states that:

> 2018-05-30  2:14:33 5128 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all
>   aria_log.######## files

So as per your log for removing that files you have to **Go to /xampp/mysql/data/**

and **Remove the Files which names start with aria_log.** which means all the files which name start with `aria_log.###` here `#` means any string like `00001` or anyhting, so after removing that files restart xammp, it works most of the time.

Answer (score 9):

go to **xampp/mysql/data** and *delete* **aria_log.00001**