# Error - XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

> 11:27:57  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 11:27:57  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 11:27:57  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 11:27:57  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 11:27:57  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 11:27:57  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

Here is the contents of the error log:

> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 4dc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:23 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.38-83.0 started; log sequence number 3088998
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 2020 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
>   Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x208b)
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>   2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
>
> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. While Trying to start Mysql on Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591504/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-while-trying-to-start-mysql-on-xampp)

Comment: This issue has already been answered, & i have also used it. [this will help your sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170937/how-to-fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-due-to-plugin-aria)

Answer (score 4):

In your error log there is log which states that:

> 2018-08-18 11:53:24 1244 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed.
>   Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all
>   aria_log.######## files

So as per your log for removing that files you have to **Go to /xampp/mysql/data/**

and **Remove the Files which names start with aria_log.######** which means all the files which name start with `aria_log.###` here `#` means any string like `00001` or anyhting, so after removing that files restart xammp, it will work definitely.