# mysql server on xampp do not works

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I know that some questions like mine is in this site and i try all of Those questions to solve my problem But I failed, so i ask new question.

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me some errors. I had started it just before, but now it isn't working.

```
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
4:29:11 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Here is the contents of the error log:

```
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: log data error last_log_page:   (1,0x2000) is 
less than checkpoint page: (1,0x4000)
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: log initialization failed
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error. 
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event 
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-17 16:25:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB.Physically writing the file full; Please wait ... 
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 113962; transaction id 9
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool 
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191217 16:25:23
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2019-12-17 16:25:23 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I have tried these solutions before but my problem was not solved

1. delete the ibdata1 file.
2. Delete all random files (except the actual database folders) in mysql/data/
3. Add innodb_force_recovery = 4 below the [mysqld] in the mysql config file (my.ini)
4. delete the ibdata1 & ib_logfile*(ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile101) file
5. Change the location of all files (like test_db) in C:\xampp\mysql\data location for test
6. change the mysql server port to "3307,3308,9999,6542"

in this places-->

```
[mysqld]
port=3306

and

[client]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Having done 1. and 2. and 4. I would suggest you have burned all your bridges. I think you are just going to have to reinstall XAMPP and start again. Hopefully you did a backup of the databases you were working on

Comment: If you open the XAMPP control panel, and hit the netstat button it will show what application is using port 3306.

Comment: Are you saying that it has worked and you did some work in mariaDB but now it does not work? Or is this happening on the first/second attempt to start mariaDB

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was working with mysql Yesterday but now ...

Comment: The ARIA storage engine is what mariaDB uses for its own internal database. If thats not functioning, neither is mariaDB

Answer (score 6):

The solution is Removing the "aria_log.00000001" file. You can find this file in \xampp\mysql\data. Then restart or start xampp. Also Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files’

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170937/how-to-fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-due-to-plugin-aria

Comment: @RiggsFolly acutally -> https://maheshwaghmare.com/mysqld-exe-aria-recovery-failed-please-run-aria_chk-r-on-all-aria-tables-and-delete-all-aria_log-files/

Answer (score 1):

**Possibilties:**
*incorrect config* - try to restore some known good config
*blocked port* - quite often its skype(especially older versions of skype), try changing MySQL port

> If you're not running XAMPP as an administrator, shutting down MySQL
>   can cause corruption which means you have to repair or delete your
>   tables. This can easily be avoided by running XAMPP as administrator.