# "Error establishing a database connection" MariaDB has stopped working - Wordpress Packaged by Bitnami localhost

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, localhost, runtime-error, bitnami

I installed Wordpress Packaged by Bitnami and made a website on it. It was working fine the whole month but now the website stopped working and when access any of the following

- http://localhost/wordpress/
- http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin
- http://localhost/wordpress/phpmyadmin

I get the following error "Error establishing a database connection"

**Manger Tool > Manage Servers** shows MariaDB Database Stopped, Apache Web Server Running

When try to Start MariaDB it doesn't start and I get the following:

**Manger Tool > Server Events**

```
Starting MariaDB Database... Exit code: 1 Stdout:

Stderr: Unknown error starting mysql
```

[image]

[image]

What's the cause and solution?

**mysqld**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the mysqld log file regarding the errors you have, which are triggering it to not to run.

which is in `/bitnami/wordpress-5.8.1-2/mariadb/data/mysqld.log`

in this file you will find detailed information about the error.

**UPDATE**

After attaching the log file, I discovered that this issue is similar to this one [How to fix Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly on Xampp due to Plugin 'Aria'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170937/how-to-fix-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-due-to-plugin-aria/41170972#41170972), and solution might be applied following the steps:

1. Remove `aria_log_control` file from `/bitnami/wordpress-5.8.1-2/mariadb/data/`
2. Start the service

Comment: mysqld is now attached. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for attaching details. Here is a solution, how to fix this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/41170972/17640172
Could you please check if it works for you?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. MariaDB has started running and my website is live now. You may update your answer so I can accept it as solution.

Comment: That's great news! Just updated the answer