# Is there any way to get my WP database if I've lost access to root on mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Few minutes ago I've done very unecessary move. I wanted to change password to root on my localhost server (I'm using WAMP any my MYSQL version is 5.7.21) and I picked the "SHA-256" option, now I have these errors in my PHPMyAdmin Panel:

```
#2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password]

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I've had an wordpress database on my local server and mainly everything that I want is just to recover it, or also change the root password to do anything... I've read some questions there and the method with changing

```
default-authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

in "my.ini" isn't working for me. I tried to run init file with

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

and it's not working too. Is there any other way to change my password or only recover my wp database from it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934745/restore-the-mysql-database-from-frm-files

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just copied my database files from mysql>data and ibdata1 file to my fresh mysql install and it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore the mysql database from .frm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934745/restore-the-mysql-database-from-frm-files)