# Restore table structure from frm and ibd files

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I am trying to restore a database in PMA but only have access to frm and ibd files - not the ib_log files which I understand you need.

I know I may not be able to recover the database data but is it possible to recover the structure of the tables from the frm files?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I restored the table from only `.frm` and `.idb` files.

#### Get the SQL query to create the tables

If you already know the schema of your tables, you can skip this step.

1. First, install [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/).
   Then you can use `mysqlfrm` command in command prompt (cmd).
2. Second, get the SQL queries from `.frm` files using `mysqlfrm` command:

   ```
   mysqlfrm --diagnostic <path>/example_table.frm
   ```

Then you can get the SQL query to create same structured table.
Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `photo_url` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `active` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `plan` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY `PRIMARY` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

#### Create the tables

Create the table(s) using the above SQL query.

If the old data still exists, you may have to drop the respective database and tables first. Make sure you have a backup of the data files.

#### Restore the data

Run this query to remove new table data:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

This removes connections between the new `.frm` file and the (new, empty) `.idb` file. Also, remove the `.idb` file in the folder.

Then, put the old `.idb` file into the new folder, e.g.:

```
cp backup/example_table.ibd <path>/example_table.idb
```

Make sure that the `.ibd` files can be read by the `mysql` user, e.g. by running `chown -R mysql:mysql *.ibd` in the folder.

Run this query to import old data:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

This imports data from the `.idb` file and will restore the data.

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error when I run import query "#1812 - Tablespace is missing for table `wallipop`.`categories`."

Comment: I fixed that by changing ownership of file but now I'm getting "#1808 - Schema mismatch (Table has ROW_TYPE_DYNAMIC row format, .ibd file has ROW_TYPE_COMPACT row format)."

Comment: For anyone else that comes's across the ROW_TYPE_DYNAMIC issue like I just did.  You'll have to start the process over from beginning and on your create table statements add `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT` after `ENGINE=InnoDB` so it looks like `) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` for example.  Then repeat the steps like normal and it should work.

Comment: hey please guide me how to do permission/ownership step on windows?
Make sure that the .ibd files can be read by the mysql user, e.g. by running chown -R mysql:mysql *.ibd in the folder.

Comment: If you have tons of .frm files ?

Comment: Are you sure it is idb files, not ibd ?

Comment: If I use `--server` instead of `--diagnostic` I get this error: _UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)_. Can I somehow solve this or I'm forced to use `--diagnostic` mode in this case?

Comment: @JeffWilbert After doing as you said I still cannot import the `.ibd`, but this time I get: _Schema mismatch (Clustered index validation failed. Because the .cfg file is missing, table definition of the IBD file could be different. Or the data file itself is already corrupted.)_

Comment: It works for me !!!
I try in wamp v3....
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

InnoDB needs the ib_log files for data recovery, but it also needs the ibdata1 file which contains the data dictionary and sometimes contains pending data for the tables.

The data dictionary is kind of a duplicate system that records table structure and also matches a table id to the physical .ibd file that contains the table data.

You can't just move .ibd files around without the InnoDB data dictionary, and the data dictionary must match the table id found inside the .ibd file. You *can* reattach a .ibd file and recover the data, but the procedure is not for the faint of heart. See http://www.chriscalender.com/recovering-an-innodb-table-from-only-an-ibd-file/

You can recover the structure using the .frm files with some file trickery, but you will not be able to create them as InnoDB tables at first. Here's a blog that covers a method for recovering .frm files as MyISAM tables:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/12/17/recovering-create-table-statement-from-frm-file/

You won't be able to use PMA for this. You need superuser access to the data directory on the server.

Comment: I'd like to second Peter's way to recover the structure from .frm files. Just make sure MySQL version is lower than 5.6. 5.6 will complain the number of columns in the fake table is less than in frm file.

Answer (score 3):

After years i wanna join in the discussion to share my solution, founded yesterday when i met the same issue.

I searched and tried tons of different stuff (like use Mysql Utilities script), recreate the table and so on ... but the real solution was a bit more easy (and tricky) to do:

`Step 1)`

- Backup old data folder (usually under `mysql/data` path)

`Step 2)`

- Format or install somewhere else a fresh and clear mysql-server

`Step 3)`

- Import from the backup (step 1) **the folder(s)** containing the frm/idb files in `mysql/data`

*Note: ONLY the folders not all the files*

`Step 4)`

- Import from the backup (step 1) the file called `ibdata1` and overwrite it in the fresh mysql installation

`Step 5)`

- Restart the mysql server (this may ask some seconds before boot-up, just wait)

And that's all! Mysql server should boot-up normally after some seconds and if nothing is corrupted, files should be restored!

Little image to explain better:
[image: oldbackup]

**Explanation:**

*- Blue:* files to import in the new mysql-server (step 3)

*- Red:* files to **NOT** import in the new mysql-server

*- Green:* ibdata1 file to import in the new mysql-server (step 4)

Answer (score 2):

You can recover table structure from .frm files and data from ibd files.

Using mysqlfrm tool which is part of [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities/)

`shell> mysqlfrm --diagnostic myfile.frm`

Recreate the table in a database of the same name using table structure.

`mysql> CREATE mytable (int i);`

Discard the tablespace of the newly created table.

`mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE;`

Copy the orphan .idb file from your backup directory to the new database directory. Ensure that the .ibd file has the necessary file permissions.

Import the orphan .ibd file. A warning is issued indicating that InnoDB will attempt to import the file without schema verification.

`mysql> ALTER TABLE r IMPORT TABLESPACE;SHOW WARNINGS;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with mysql utility.

From book.frm file to a file book.sql:

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:mysqladmin@localhost:3306 D:\yahwehdb\yahweh_altera\book.frm > D:\yahwehdb\yahweh_altera\book.frm\book.sql --diagnostic --port=3307 --user=root
```

From a directory containing all .frm file to a file all.sql:

```
mysqlfrm --server=root:mysqladmin@localhost:3306 D:\yahwehdb\yahweh_altera > D:\yahwehdb\yahweh_altera\all.sql --diagnostic --port=3307 --user=root
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually quite easy as long as you know how to do it, and no external software or shell commands are needed.

The database data is stored in C:\xampp\mysql\data\ or similar by default. The folders are the database tables. Inside each folder, the .frm file are the columns. The .ibd hold the row values.

First create the database(s) in PHPMyAdmin.

Get the SQL query generated from this site, under menu Recover structure > From .frm file:

https://recovery.twindb.com/

Upload each .frm file, and then copy and paste these queries into the SQL command to create the tables in PHPMyAdmin.

Then, on each table, do this SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE
```

This will automatically remove the new .ibd file from the database directory.
Copy the old .ibd file into the database folder.
Run the following command to activate the table again:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE
```

And that's it! You should be able to view and access all of your old values again.

Comment: the website cacnt be opened why?