# Restore MYSQL table data with ibd or frm files

Tags: mysql, database, tablespace, frm

I want to restore my table data with available file type .frm and .idb, based on [this link](http://www.voxteneo.com/restoring-tables-mysql-database-frm-ibd-files-available/). It was going smoothly until step 3, which gives Error Code 1030, Got error -1 from storage engine. It's a query to discard tablespace and remove idb file after I created new table structure.

So, I experimentally decided to manually delete idb file from mysql folder, and after that replace it with back up idb file. Say the step 3 succeeded, I can execute step 5 to reactivate the tablespace. Since it was a failure, however, I just copied it and restart the database, yet when I ran it, the table is empty.

Is there any step missing? Or if we have to use step 3 query to succeed, how to deal with error 1030? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I hope, this link will help you on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868956/restore-table-structure-from-frm-and-ibd-files

Comment: This question is not about programming at all, so it is not really on topic here at SO in the first place. If you still have questions, then I suggest you post them at our DBA sister site.