# Internal error: Drop all secondary indexes before importing table onlinelogistics/users when .cfg file is missing

Tags: mysql

I want to recover sql tables from ibd file.

I followed these steps but it didn't work.
First I discarded tablespace using command Alter table users disard tablespace.
Then, i deleted newly generated users.idb file
Then, I copied required users.ibd file to that database in mysql/data/onlinelogistics folder
then, i tried to import tablespace but it showed this error

**#1815 - Internal error: Drop all secondary indexes before importing table onlinelogistics/users when .cfg file is missing.**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKejv.png)

Comment: Corrected the tags, because this is clearly about `MySQL`, (and not so much about `sql`.

Comment: And `ibd` file also contains info about indexes uses in the table(s).  You should not mess around with those `ibd` files.  (unless you really like this kind of errors)

Comment: I do see that in the docs from 5.6 this is actually a way of [Importing a Tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-import.html#innodb-table-import-example), which describes how to mess around with `ibd` files, but  at pint 4 they say: "Copy the .ibd file **and** .cfg metadata".   you should NOT copy a `ibd` file if you do not have the `cfg` file which belong together.

Comment: You can import Tablespace without cfg. You can read it in the link above by @Luuk You can read that if you want to restore from a crash you don't need cfg. When you create your table you need to leave the secondary keys. Then you can import the table and the tablespace too. If the keys are important you need to solve it after importing.

Comment: it's so polite when somebody get crashed server and loss many files, you guy still criticize for not enough bullshit files require by mysql

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an [additional check](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/89445b64fef2c3c9f2cfb9f572dd19b88f3a48df) which was included in MariaDB 10.5.13 to fix [MDEV-26131: SEGV in ha_innobase::discard_or_import_tablespace](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26131)

There doesn't seem to be a "fix" or workaround except for dropping all indices before attempting to import that `ibd`. Alternatively, you could use an MariaDB server that does not include this change

Comment: drop indices and they show error or scheme mismatching. bullshit mariadb

Answer (score 1):

For restoring/importing your `.ibd` file based on `.frm` file, simply follow exactly the [instruction here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868956/restore-table-structure-from-frm-and-ibd-files/48207488#48207488) and then you should **REMOVE ALL FORIEGN KEYS** on your table structure before running

```
ALTER TABLE example_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

command.