# The database disappeared

Tags: phpmyadmin

The database disappeared, poked in the phpmyadmin settings, clicked next and now there is only information_schema and performance_schema. I searched, there were database tables in ibd format. how do I get everything back as it was before my jamb actions?

I tried some options from the Internet, nothing happened. what should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868956/restore-table-structure-from-frm-and-ibd-files

Comment: Explain what you tried and what the outcome is. mysqlfrm seems useful. Your question requires more details.